# Radio Selection before search

Tags: mobile, search, search-results, faceted-search, component

**Context**

Allowing users to search for any particular job based on multiple parameters.

**Feedback needed**

I've designed this application search component, which will have a default selection and the user can only search within that selection. They can, however, select any other parameter and search accordingly. I'm confused because I'm restricting user open search behavior and the interaction involves multiple selections to perform the action.

**Can anyone comment on the pattern that I've implemented or share any similar examples they've come across?**

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: "They can, however, select any other parameter" what parameters, can you post the screenshots of the whole process?  What you have now, seems to be restricted to a single parameter, i.e. searching only withing "Garri Number" (if "Garri Number" is a radio button).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you want to search for different attributes (gaari [whatever that is], driver, container, job numbers).

How much do these numbers differ? E.g., do driver numbers begin with "D-" and container numbers with "C"? If the user can designate which number to search by entering the correct format, you don't need the selection of the attribute.

Even if the number formats don't differ, or users need to search for partial information, or ..., you can delay the initial selection to a time when the result list is shown. Group the result list, or - if it's large - allow filtering for your attributes. In this way, you move the selection to the end of the interaction, when the system has determined there are searh results in multiple categories, and a selection is actually required.

(Even if there are two hits in each category, showing 8 hits might actually not even in this case need a user selection, because 8 hits fit onto a screen and the user may pick the correct search result immediately.)